# Is it possible to close vlc to system tray?

Tags: vlc, settings

I have recently installed **vlc remote** in my phone and I can't use it unless vlc is opened so I was wondering if it is possible to always keep VLC opened like skype and utorrent in windows,
Thanks in advance,

Comment: As of 2017, the working solutoin is https://askubuntu.com/a/831470/186295

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to Tools>Preferences
2. Under interface you will find two options to mark, I have marked them for you in this image:
   [image: preferences window of VLC]

Check "Systray popup when minimized"
Check "Show systray icon"

3.
Close VLC.

4.
Now open it using:

```
vlc --qt-start-minimized
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: For added convenience, put that command in your start up applications so you don't need to remember to launch it every time.

Comment: Is "Systray popup when minimized" option removed or is it ubuntu specific? Can't find on windows. Running 2.1.3

Comment: Should be cross platform, but I can't check since I have no windows machine at hand

Comment: No luck at finding it at windows :) Is it still available in 2.1.3 on ubuntu? (I on the other hand only use Debian box without gui ;)

Comment: it changed to 'show media change popup:' with options: when minimized, always, or never. (on windows and ubuntu, but it's not critical to minimizing)

Comment: This setting is gone, Ubuntu, VLC 3.0.7.

Answer (score 22):

With version 2.1.6 'Systray popup when minimized' option doesn't exist anymore. To hide vlc simply click on the vlc systray icon.

Comment: huh, so simple and I couldn't figure out. Is there no in-app control for that btw?

Comment: Works great in Windows, VLC 2.1.5. Thanks for sharing & +1.

Comment: Also works with Fedora and VLC 3.0 git.

Comment: Sweet! It also works on KDE Plasma.

Answer (score 7):

For newer version of VLC you'll have to right click the icon in systray and select "Hide VLC media player in taskbar".

Comment: Thank you for providing the only working solution for current VLC versions

Comment: Double-clicking the VLC icon on the systray will show/hide the VLC window (at least on GNOME 3). It took me a while to discover it...

Comment: @JuliánLanderreche: Thank you for the tip! it is way better than other solutions

Answer (score 3):

I think, you need for background music play and you anyways get the controls on-screen while playing video. The latest version VLC Media Player does not have the option of 'Systray popup when minimized' and in my case, the systray icon is also not shown. So, I came up with another idea of using something which Linux provides by default. I used two workspaces.

One is for my works and other where the VLC is running but you still get the controls in the Sound Systray Icon.

Following pictures show how I am managing:

#### VLC Media Player on Workspace 2:

[image]

#### The control of the VLC Media Player in my workspace:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it is inside the QT menu:

[image]