# How to close programs but still running in background

Tags: vlc

There are music player name Rhytmbox so if you just close the program it will still running in the background.

But i don't like rhythmbox, instead i am using VLC to play music. How do i can close the program but it will be still running in the background, so if i do alt + tab it will be clean from it.

Comment: You can minimize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to close vlc to system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300617/is-it-possible-to-close-vlc-to-system-tray)

Comment: I know it, but i want to close instead minimize.  

I don't think so, i already figure out that setting before ask this, but not that one

Answer (score 1):

I know how to make it clean if we do **ALT + TAB**, but it not solve the problem to make the program is closed and running in the background.

The solution is we move the VLC to another activities or another desktop (press Windows key (Super)). Just drag the windows of the VLC to another Desktop.

[image: DRAG THE WINDOW (VLC) INTO NEW DESKTOP]

Comment: That is a smart workaround :-) ... But, there might be a simpler way ... Please see the post I linked to under your question.

Comment: Thanks for the post mate, but i think that not what i looking for 

Comment: OK ... got you(*I think*) ... You need `vlc -I dummy MediaFile` or `cvlc MediaFile` ... `MediaFile` is your audio or video file ... Run that from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your attention mate, actually i just had to click 'hide VLC' on the icon

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I figured out how to close it specifically for VLC, it's very easy.
Just click on the VLC icon near the clock > then click Hide VLC Media player

[image: Click hide VLC Media Player]